# Paypal Webhooks - Converting Post body values to object

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal

I'm working with Paypal Webhooks. When the customer changes their billing plan or purchases a service, Paypal makes a POST message to my server to inform me of what changes have been made. The body of the POST message contains JSON information about changes that have occurred to the account. Does anyone know the correct way to convert the received JSON into a normal C# Paypal Object?

I'm aware that I could use something like NewtonSoft but I am trying to find the "By the book way", unfortunately, the Paypal book is a bit of a mess.

I have had a look through the paypal Api but cant see a method that would do it.

Comment: Outside of finding a library someone else has written, NewtonSoft is about as "by the book" as you can get.

Comment: Unfortunately, if I do this it means creating a different type of object for every single type of Post message (there's a whole list of them). I'm hoping there's someone out there that's been through this process and knows a really easy answer that will avoid it.

Comment: Would deserializing to an anonymous type help? Then you could work from the expected field names rather than define every type of return long hand.

Comment: Thanks. Annonymous types was not something i've used before. Googled it and it is a great solution until I find a better one.